# How to loop over an object inside of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

The server gives the following response:

```
SomeObject:{
    Object1:{
        id: 123456789,
        name: "Foo"
    },
    Object2:{
        id: 123456789,
        name: "Bar"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to loop over `SomeObject` and display both the `id` and `name` of `Object1/Object2`? Searching for this mostly lead to using `Object.keys(SomeObject).map` however those are use to get the string of `Object1/Object2`.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Preferably {id} {name} for each of the objects

Comment: `for (const item of SomeObject) { var id = item.id; console.log(id) };`

Comment: Use Object.values(obj) instead of Object.keys(obj)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const SomeObject = { Object1: { id: 123456789, name: "Foo" }, Object2:{ id: 123456789, name: "Bar" } };

const res = 
  Object.values(SomeObject)
  .forEach(({ id, name }) => console.log(id, name));
```

Comment: So Object.values returns the objects and then you "extract" id and name within the for each? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes ``Object#values`` would return ``[ { "id": 123456789, "name": "Foo" }, { "id": 123456789,  "name": "Bar" } ]``.  Using ``Array#forEach``, we then iterate over it, destructure the id and name from each item and print them.

Comment: Ah okay that makes it very clear.

Comment: @Sylent to be clear, this assumes you know the objects schema. If you want a more generic approach, you can see my answer. This obviously is cleaner as a piece of code but can only ever be applied to this specific use case.

Comment: @BenjaminJamesKippax That indeed looks quite universal. I'm currently messing around with react and mongodb and I'm also considering changing up the server's response.

Comment: @Sylent Good stuff. You could add in callback params to my initial function to make it even more extensible.

Comment: @BenjaminJamesKippax wouldn't this issue immediately be resolved if I returned an array of each individual object so we could use map?

Comment: @Sylent generally that would depend on exactly what you want to achieve, what you'll be using the data for. If you'll always transform the data from that endpoint into some other schema/object, why not just return that from the endpoint, or why not create another endpoint which returns the schema you want?

Answer (score 1):

One way is with Object.values then forEach.

```
SomeObject = {
    Object1:{
        id: 123456789,
        name: "Foo"
    },
    Object2:{
        id: 123456789,
        name: "Bar"
    }
}

Object.values(SomeObject).forEach(function (value) {
     console.log(value.id);
     //value.name
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach utilizing two forin loop.

```js
    obj = {
        SomeObject: {
            Object1: {
                id: 123456789,
                name: "Foo"
            },
            Object2: {
                id: 123456789,
                name: "Bar"
            }
        }
    }

    for (const key in obj) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
            const
                obj2 = obj[key];
            for (const key2 in obj2) {
                if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(obj2, key2)) {
                    inner_obj2 = obj2[key2];
                    console.log(inner_obj2.id, inner_obj2.name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you have an object with an unknown amount of properties but you know all of those properties would be objects you can do this ...

```
let obj = {
    prop1: {
    id: 1,
    someProp: { subId: 's1' }
  },
  propA: {
    id: 2,
    someProp: { subId: 's2' }
  },
  prop3: {
    id: 3,
    someProp: { subId: 's3' }
  }
}

/**
* Recursively iterate an object and its properties.
* @param {object} theObj the object to be iterated
*/
function iterate(theObj) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(theObj)) {
        console.log(`type of ${key} = ${typeof theObj[key]}`);
        // do something
        if (typeof theObj[key] == 'object') {
            iterate(theObj[key]);
        }
    }
}

iterate(obj);

// output
// type of prop1 = object
// type of id = number
// type of someProp = object
// type of subId = string
// type of propA = object
// type of id = number
// type of someProp = object
// type of subId = string
// type of prop3 = object
// type of id = number
// type of someProp = object
// type of subId = string
```

It's by no means perfect but it works for objects and arrays.
Even tried it with this piece of madness.

```
let arr = [
    0,
    'test',
    {
        id: 1,
        subarr: [
            32,
            45,
            76
        ],
        subObj: {
            key:'foo',
            lock: 'bar'
        }
    }
]

iterate(arr);

// output
// type of 0 = number
// type of 1 = string
// type of 2 = object
// type of id = number
// type of subarr = object
// type of 0 = number
// type of 1 = number
// type of 2 = number
// type of subObj = object
// type of key = string
// type of lock = string
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving this is the `Object.values()` method, the result of which can be iterated using a `for..of` or `.forEach()` loop:

```js
const SomeObject = { Object1: { id: 123456789, name: "Foo" }, Object2:{ id: 123456789, name: "Bar" } };

for( let {id,name} of Object.values( SomeObject ) ) {
    console.log( id, name );
}
```